# how to create a personalized install cd/pendrive of ubuntu according to my needs?(remastersys is no more)

Tags: installation, iso

I have read many such **similar questions**,but they **don't satisfy my needs** because **they are outdated**

now currently I have a desktop with Ubuntu 12.10 installed on it.I would be using this desktop for few more months.

I have already installed a lot of software on this pc.Soon,when I would be getting a new laptop,I wish to install Ubuntu from a personalized CD/ pen drive so that I won't have to waste a lot of data usage and time on re downloading the softwares.

also I wish to make some changes in the core structure itself(because it's easy,i think). ***remastersys was a good option,but now it dead.***

i would use a .iso file or the installation itself to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't get the answer that exactly matches your question, here's an alternative solution I can suggest to meet your requirement.

You can **Clonezilla** your Ubuntu partition, i.e. save it using Clonezilla, and than **Restore** it to another computer. Ubuntu will automatically adjust itself to the new hardware configuration.

You only need to take care of the source and target partition number as well as the size (and also any other partition ids registered in your fstab file), which is quite easy if you read the documentantion on Clonezilla website: http://clonezilla.org/

**One more important point:**

Before starting this **cloning** operation you should better uninstall or at least disable any proprietary hardware (e.g. like video card) drivers and install/enable/use open source alternatives if the target computer does not have that same hardware in order to avoid problems.

Comment: but my system is 32 bit(i386) and clonezilla seems to be available only for 64 bit architecture.

Comment: 1) I prefer using it in **Parted Magic** and it supports both archs in a single iso: https://partedmagic.com/ 2) You can select your arch from **Clonezilla** download page: http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable